# Can I click on a button on a MS Access form while a subroutine is running?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a progress bar, a tiny pop up form, linked to the progress of a time consuming subroutine.

I'm trying to put a cancel button on the progress bar. When the subroutine is running in the background, I can't click on anything in the progress bar form.

Is there a way to click a button on a different form while a subroutine is ongoing?

Comment: Look into `DoEvents`. Not sure if it will work for you but worth a try as alternatives will probably be difficult. For example one alternative is to run the subroutine on a separate Access file with the relevant tables linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use `DoEvents` to tell VBA to keep pumping/processing Windows Messages; the result might not be as responsive as truly asynchronous code could be, but should be enough to enable clicking a [Cancel] button and process cancellation.

---

The code in [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/01/12/progress-indicator/) (disclaimer: I wrote it) was originally written for Excel and uses a `UserForm` (which is hidden in the VBE when the host is Access, but Access VBA projects can absolutely contain and consume `UserForm` modules).

You'll want to remove the Excel-specific bits, like `QualifyMacroName` here:

```
Private Function QualifyMacroName(ByVal book As Workbook, ByVal procedure As String) As String
    QualifyMacroName = "'" & book.FullName & "'!" & procedure
End Function
```

And then modify the `Create` factory method to *require* the `instance` parameter, like this:

```
Public Function Create(ByVal procedure As String, ByVal instance As Object, Optional ByVal initialLabelValue As String, Optional ByVal initialCaptionValue As String, Optional ByVal completedSleepMilliseconds As Long = 1000, Optional canCancel As Boolean = False) As ProgressIndicator

    Dim result As ProgressIndicator
    Set result = New ProgressIndicator

    result.Cancellable = canCancel
    result.SleepMilliseconds = completedSleepMilliseconds

    If Not instance Is Nothing Then
        Set result.OwnerInstance = instance
    Else
        Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "Invalid argument: 'instance' must be a valid object reference."
    End If

    result.ProcedureName = procedure

    If initialLabelValue <> vbNullString Then result.ProgressView.ProgressLabel = initialLabelValue
    If initialCaptionValue <> vbNullString Then result.ProgressView.Caption = initialCaptionValue

    Set Create = result

End Function
```

Once it compiles, you can use the `ProgressIndicator` by registering a worker method that does the actual work, like this:

```
With ProgressIndicator.Create("Run", New MyLongRunningMacro, canCancel:=True)
    .Execute
End With
```

Where `MyLongRunningMacro` is a class module with a `Run` method that might look something like this:

```
Public Sub Run(ByVal progress As ProgressIndicator)
    Dim thingsDone As Long
    For Each thing In ThingsToDo
        Application.Run thing
        thingsDone = thingsDone + 1
        progress.UpdatePercent thingsDone / ThingsToDo.Count
        If ShouldCancel(progress) Then
            ' user confirmed they want to cancel the whole thing.
            ' perform any clean-up or rollback here
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function ShouldCancel(ByVal progress As ProgressIndicator) As Boolean
    If progress.IsCancelRequested Then
        If MsgBox("Cancel this operation?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            ShouldCancel = True
        Else
            progress.AbortCancellation
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Where `ThingsToDo` might be a collection of macros to execute, for example. Reporting progress percent is easier with a loop, but while it can also work with a sequence of operations, cleanly handling cancellation is a bit harder:

```
Public Sub Run(ByVal progress As ProgressIndicator)
    Dim thingsDone As Long
    DoThingOne
    If Not UpdateAndContinue(progress, 0.33) Then Exit Sub
    DoThingTwo
    If Not UpdateAndContinue(progress, 0.66) Then Exit Sub
    DoThingThree
    If Not UpdateAndContinue(progress, 1) Then Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Function UpdateAndContinue(ByVal progress As ProgressIndicator, ByVal percentCompleted As Double) As Boolean
    progress.UpdatePercent percentCompleted
    If ShouldCancel(progress) Then 
        ' user confirmed they want to cancel the whole thing.
        ' perform any clean-up or rollback here
        Exit Function
    Else 
        UpdateAndContinue = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This answer is probably way more involved than I need for my situation BUT it's always good to learn from answers like these!

Comment: @F.Lost what *this* progress indicator does differently than everybody else's, is total and complete decoupling from the worker logic; as a result the `ProgressIndicator` can be reused everywhere it's needed, without needing to change a single line of code (be it in the form's code-behind or the class module): you simply register a worker method for it. All you need to do then, is to write your progress-updating worker logic in a method that takes a `ProgressIndicator` parameter, `Update` it as needed, and periodically check whether `IsCancelRequested` to cleanly handle cancellation.